# Wordpress Loop get_the_id()

Tags: wordpress

I tried the following functions in header.php, footer.php, single.php etc.

```
var_dump(in_the_loop());
var_dump(get_the_id());
```

The first function gives false (meaning we are not in the loop) and the second function gives the post id every single time.

Description of `get_the_id()` from wordpress :

> Retrieve the numeric ID of the current post. This tag must be within The Loop.

I just want a simple explanation what the hell is going on why do i get the post id if I call the function out of the loop !?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**must** is a little strong for get_the_id() ...*delivers evil eye to Wordpress*.

It works in the header and non-loop (confirmed).

Please note that post/page are essentially interchangeable in this conversation.

Think of WP this way -> You always have a post id in some way, all the time, every page, unless you do weird stuff or talk about non-page edge cases. When you are at the install root (such as site.com/) there are posts being called, something has to be displayed. There are other settings that will impact post/page such as static front page settings. On a category listing, if there are pages, I got the first ID returned before the loop.

On post/pages the page ID is (more or less0 set before the loop. This is a result of the URL (pretty or ?p=123 format) dictating the content.  Using pretty names, the page at site.com/foo-bar/ will try to look up if there is content available via the permalink rules for "foo-bar". If there is content, the post ID is obtained. (simplified)

Later in the page build you get into the loop. However, before the loop you are also offered opportunities to change, sort, or augment the loop - such as changing the page IDs to be looped or sorting.

Regarding `in_the_loop()`, WP says

> "True if caller is within loop, false if loop hasn't started or has ended." via http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_the_loop

`in_the_loop()` evaluates if the loop is in action (loop being key to the WP world). Also important - when you are in the loop WP can iterate over multiple page/post (IDs).

I don't have a 100% bulletproof explanation as to how the ID always shows, but when you dig into the API and various methods for hooking this might be a result.

I understand your confusion and agree with you. I think WP intended `get_the_id()` as a loop based tool, outside the loop you will get unpredictable results.

Hope that helps, I do enjoy working in WP, and I hope you do to.